# phantom JS for IE/Firefox

Tags: c#, phantomjs

just a question please : does phantomJS support firefox and Internet explorer? 
I mean, is it able to **launch** these web browser in order to make some automation tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS is an headless version of a Webkit browser (such older versions of Google Chrome), so it doesn't launch any browser but itself.

For Firefox have a look to [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/), while for Internet Explorer your only solution is [TrifleJS](http://triflejs.org/).

Other solutions might imply to use Karma, Jasmine, [Watir](http://watir.com/), [WaitN](http://watin.org/) with VMs, [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) or [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/).

Comment: Just a small correction, PhantomJS is not a headless version of Google Chrome. It uses a WebKit as a web engine. Google Chrome was based on it before April 2013.

Comment: Thanks guy, just updated the answer with your comments.

Comment: I want to use TrifleJS in my C# code but I can't find any doc about how can I add TrifleJS driver. In TrifleJS website  says: "The API is coded as a port of PhantomJS. Perfect for test automation. If you have used phantom before then you already know how to use TrifleJS." I can use PhantomJS in my code but still I can't figure out how to use TrifleJS. Do you have any idea? Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far?